# How to display multiple lines of text in bing maps pushpin?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bing-maps

I am adding pushpins with foreach loop to the map like this:

```
Pushpin p = new Pushpin() { Location = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location { Latitude = n.latitude, Longitude = n.longtitude} };
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string houseNumber { get; set; }
    public double longtitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
}
```

How do I add other data from Address class to the pushpin, so it would look something like this?
[Pushpin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrpVl.jpg)

Comment: Pushpin is a ContentControl, so you can just set an appropriate ContentTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you linked to is of an infobox. What I would recommend is create a custom UIControl that looks the way you want it to and then add that to the map rather than trying to hack up the Pushpin class. Here is a code sample:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868032.aspx

Try using a Grid with a background color to start and add your text fields.